# From the timestamp in SQL, selecting records from today, yesterday, this week, this month and between two dates php mysql

Tags: mysql, date, select, filter

Hopefully, it's an easy solution, but I am trying to filter the data for the following:-

- Today
- Yesterday
- This Week
- This Month
- In between two dates.

The date I get from the database is basically a timestamp.

This is what I tried:-

- Today

  ```
  SELECT n.title, COUNT(*) AS times FROM node_view_count WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ```
- Yesterday

  ```
  SELECT n.title, COUNT(*) AS times FROM node_view_count WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAYS)
  ```

...

It's not really working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you're selecting by date only, base your calculations on `CURDATE` (which returns date only) rather than `NOW` (which returns date and time). These examples will catch all times within the day ranges:

- Today: `WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()`
- Yesterday: `WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND timestamp < CURDATE()`
- This month: `WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())-1 DAY)`
- Between the two dates 3 June 2013 and 7 June 2013 (note how the end date is specified as 8 June, not 7 June): `WHERE timestamp >= '2013-06-03' AND timestamp < '2013-06-08'`

The "this week" depends on which day you start your week; I'll leave that to you. You can use the [`DAYOFWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function to tweak `CURDATE()` to the proper ranges.

---

**Addendum**: OP's column type was `INTEGER`, storing a UNIX timestamp, and my answer assumed the column type was `TIMESTAMP`. Here's how to do all the same things with a UNIX timestamp value and still maintain optimization if the column is indexed (as the answers above will do if the `TIMESTAMP` column is indexed)...

Basically, the solution is to just wrap the beginning and/or ending dates in the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function:

- Today: `WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())`
- Yesterday: `WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())`
- This month: `WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())-1 DAY))`
- Between the two dates 3 June 2013 and 7 June 2013 (note how the end date is specified as 8 June, not 7 June): `WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-03') AND timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-08')`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ed. It seems to be working. Only one gripe; the today seems to be showing all the records. When I do timestamp = CURDATE() instead, it doesn't show anything. any idea?

Comment: Hmm, it works for me with my small test table. What happens when you try `WHERE DATE(timestamp) = CURDATE()`? I've avoided using `DATE(timestamp)` because if you have an index on the `timestamp` column (and you probably should if you'll do a lot of these queries), using the `DATE` function on the column will kill any chance of optimization.

Comment: Hi Ed, It seems like Today and Yesterday both have problems. Today shows all, Yesterday shows none. WHERE DATE(timestamp) = CURDATE() shows none too. Month works perfectly. I think it doesn't like timestamp >= CURDATE() or timestamp < CURDATE()

Comment: Which data type is the `timestamp` column? I assumed the [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) data type and tested with that.

Comment: It's int :-( ... Is that a problem?

Comment: Oops; bad assumption on my part :) An `INT` definitely won't work with my answer. Is it a UNIX timestamp value?

Comment: Yes, it is UNIX timestamp. Thanks a lot for your assistance

Comment: No problem! In that case, I think you can just wrap all the `DATETIME` values in the answer in the MySQL [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function. For example, "Today" would be `WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())` and "Between 3 June and 8 June" would be `WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-03') AND timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-08')` and so forth. Does that make sense? More importantly, does it work? If so, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'll add the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` thing to the answer in case it's useful to anyone else - I think it will be because I see quite a few questions about dealing with UNIX timestamp values.