# get records of today, yesterday and this week

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show records of today (from yesterday 12 AM to today 11:59 PM), Yesterday, and records of this week, 
I have this query for todays records

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tblpatients` WHERE `Is_Deleted` = '0' AND `TimeStamp` <= NOW() AND `TimeStamp` >= ?????
```

I have a field in my table named TimeStamp format is 2014-09-20 12:11:20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your calculations based on `CURDATE` if you are selecting date only.

Hope the below Examples would help you

```
Today: WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
Yesterday: WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND timestamp < CURDATE()
This month: WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())-1 DAY)
Between the two dates 3 June 2013 and 7 June 2013 (note how the end date is specified as 8 June, not 7 June): WHERE timestamp >= '2013-06-03' AND timestamp < '2013-06-08'
```

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198468/from-the-timestamp-in-sql-selecting-records-from-today-yesterday-this-week-t) one too..

Comment: what should be for This Week?

Comment: use week function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736010/how-to-group-by-week-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()` and `date()` function for getting yesterday. Example....

```
$now = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time()); 
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('yesterday'));
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tblpatients` WHERE `Is_Deleted` = '0' AND `TimeStamp` <= '$now' AND `TimeStamp` >= '$yesterday'";
```

Also can use `BETWEEN` in `query` String. ie,.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblpatients WHERE Is_Deleted = '0' AND TimeStamp BETWEEN '$now' AND '$yesterday'";
```