# Get data for Charts from TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of data in several tables.  Each row has a `ts` column that is a data type TIMESTAMP, looks like this:

`2013-11-20 11:20:14`

I'd like to produce counts for each week of the year to plot a graph.  So the results I'd like are like this:

```
week1 5
week2 16
week3 19
week4 27
```

For example.  Is it possible to do this with SQL? I mean I could manually do it with a PHP script but I feel like there must be a way to use the COUNT() function in SQL to do this.

Comment: hi have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198468/from-the-timestamp-in-sql-selecting-records-from-today-yesterday-this-week-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing to much about the specifics about the table structure. I think you can do this:

```
SELECT
    WEEK(timestamp),
    COUNT(*) as nbr
FROM
    table
GROUP BY 
    WEEK(timestamp)
```

But I think it would be good to also consider year in the calculation. Like this:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(timestamp),
    WEEK(timestamp),
    COUNT(*) as nbr
FROM
    table
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(timestamp),
    WEEK(timestamp)
```

I would also think that the "week" part you can append later in your php code.

**Edit**

It is true what Juergen d said in the comment. You could also use yearweek(). Like this:

```
SELECT
    yearweek(timestamp),
    COUNT(*) as nbr
FROM
    table
GROUP BY 
    yearweek(timestamp)
```

References:

- [YEAR(date)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)
- [WEEK(date[,mode])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)
- [YEARWEEK(date), YEARWEEK(date,mode)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of those functions! I knew there must have been an easy way to do it.  Thank you!

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but for some reason the data I'm getting (the COUNT column) isnt incrementing: `// 201346
59
// 201347
44
// 201348
21
// 201349
15
// 201350
10`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about "incrementing"?

Comment: Sorry.  I realise the COUNT() is counting the entries in that week only.  I need it to include all the counts *up to* that week, so each week is the total entries from the start up to that week. I hope that makes sense :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use WEEK function in mysql

EX:

```
Select WEEK(<timesatmp>),count(*) from Table group by WEEK (<timesatmp>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `week` function to get the week number:

```
select week(ts),
    count(*)
from your_table
group by week(ts);
```

or year and week together like 201719 using `yearweek`:

```
select yearweek(ts),
    count(*)
from your_table
group by yearweek(ts);
```